# In a recorded "Let's Play" of a table-top game, what elements of the game should be shown?

Tags: podcast

I'm current planning to run a "Let's Play" for the *Scales of War* D&D campaign. I've found a battlemap program and plan to have that be the basis of the visuals.

A Let's Play is a solitaire run through a (normally) video game. I plan to take this approach and record myself playing and thinking about D&D using computer-aided map tools and character builder.

What level of detail would make an interesting recording:

- **Narrative flow**: gloss over rolls and focus mainly on characterization of antagonists and protagonists. The rolls will happen in the background and change the events of narration
- **Technical flow**: Treat the "Let's Play" as a tutorial in character theory, combat tactics, and interesting maneuvers
- **Something in the middle?**
- Other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's just one person solo, I am not sure either is all that interesting; I probably wouldn't watch such a thing myself. Certainly the narrative flow wouldn't really be, and the technical would only be useful inasmuch it's an instructional "how to play D&D 101." If going for that, I would definitely show how the game fiction and rules interact. I might watch something like that for a new game system I don't know.

In a computer game case, one player and computer makes a lot more sense. In this case, it's a weird atypical mix of one GM and same person as player without the GM/player division or multiperson group that is usually distinctive to RPGs.

Answer (score 2):

Middle, leaning a little toward technical — if I'm listening to a "Let's Play," I'm most interested in hearing how the systems work when used.

Answer (score 2):

Neither the narrative or the technical are as important as the second word you added to both. Flow is what you should focus on. Whether its you and the players fooling around or everyone thumbing through the rule books you need to keep a smooth flow to your recording. Don't be chatting up a storm and suddenly have everyone become quiet as they start looking for a rule, ease between the steps and if possible keep talking. Sure you can cut out dead air later but if you have to maybe that rule was not important enough. But overall the best you can get is if you and the players forget you are even being recorded and just play the game. If you can do that people will notice the honesty in your gaming and enjoy it as if they had been there at the table listening in.